# Minimize chrome ribbon button in python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, robotframework

I have python selenium code to expand chrome button as mentioned below.

```
button.click()
```

And it expands button like this:

[image: Chrome button expansion]

Now I want to minimize button. Is there any method like `button.unclick()`?

Comment: Just do `element.click()` on the `element` you normally click to minimize, which I suspect it is the dropdown arrow in your screenshot.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, it's a folder. It expands when click.

Comment: Please share HTML source for this element.